# Is it possible to optimize the following boolean checks?

Tags: python, optimization, unit-testing, google-app-engine

The following code works and it prints out only `True` as it is supposed to, for all the different cases:

```
class User(object):
  def __init__(self, key):
    self.key = key

def is_ok(user_dbs, self_db):
  count = len(user_dbs)
  if not self_db:
    return not count
  return (count != 1 or self_db.key == user_dbs[0].key) and count != 2

print 'Should print only True:'
print is_ok([],                 None)    is True   # found nothing and no self
print is_ok([],                 User(1)) is True   # found nothing and self
print is_ok([User(1)],          None)    is False  # found one and no self
print is_ok([User(1)],          User(1)) is True   # found one and it is you
print is_ok([User(2)],          User(1)) is False  # found one and it is not you
print is_ok([User(1), User(2)], None)    is False  # found two and no self
print is_ok([User(1), User(2)], User(1)) is False  # found two and one of them is you
print is_ok([User(2), User(1)], User(1)) is False  # found two and one of them is you
print is_ok([User(2), User(3)], User(1)) is False  # found two and none of them is you
```

---

The whole thing is to check if the username is available for a new user or when an existing user is updating his current username.

The `user_dbs` can have maximum 2 records as it has a limit in the actual query. So here is the breakdown:

- If there are 2 records then we know for sure that the particular `username` is not available.
- If there are 0 records then we know for sure that this `username` is available.
- If there is 1 record then:

  - If it's a new user then the `username` is not available
  - If it's an existing user and that user is yourself then the `username` is available, otherwise not.

So can we optimize somehow the `is_ok` function above?

Try it live: [repl.it/XHC](http://repl.it/XHC)

Comment: This is the kind of thing that database uniqueness constraints are built for. Is there a reason you are not using them instead?

Comment: @cbojar Yep.. there is no such thing on Google App Engine's Datastore unless you are using that for a key and if so it's not changeable..

Comment: I figured there was a reason, but I didn't want to jump to conclusions in either direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `is_ok` method can be optimized by eliminating the counting:

```
def is_ok(user_dbs, self_db):
    return not user_dbs or self_db.key == user_dbs[0].key and not user_dbs[1:]
```

Or, if you implement `User.__eq__` as [@mleyfman](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/47450/mleyfman) suggested (great idea btw), then you can write like this:

```
def is_ok(user_dbs, self_db):
    return not user_dbs or self_db in user_dbs and not user_dbs[1:]
```

I also recommend turning the whole thing into proper unit tests, rather than *reading* the output to check it:

```
import unittest
from test.test_support import run_unittest


class User(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.key == other.key if isinstance(other, User) else False


def is_ok(user_dbs, self_db):
    if not self_db:
        return not user_dbs
    return not user_dbs or self_db in user_dbs and not user_dbs[1:]


class TestAddingUser(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_find_nothing_and_no_self(self):
        self.assertTrue(is_ok([], None))

    def test_find_nothing_and_self(self):
        self.assertTrue(is_ok([], User(1)))

    def test_found_one_and_no_self(self):
        self.assertFalse(is_ok([User(1)], None))

    def test_found_one_and_it_is_you(self):
        self.assertTrue(is_ok([User(1)], User(1)))

    def test_found_one_and_it_is_not_you(self):
        self.assertFalse(is_ok([User(2)], User(1)))

    def test_found_two_and_no_self(self):
        self.assertFalse(is_ok([User(1), User(2)], None))

    def test_found_two_and_one_is_you(self):
        self.assertFalse(is_ok([User(1), User(2)], User(1)))
        self.assertFalse(is_ok([User(2), User(1)], User(1)))

    def test_found_two_and_none_is_you(self):
        self.assertFalse(is_ok([User(2), User(3)], User(1)))


def test_main():
    run_unittest(TestAddingUser)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_main()
```

Comment: It is indeed a good thing :)

Comment: hehe.. Thank you for that, but I didn't want to add bunch of things for this little test and wanted to keep it as small as possible.. yet accurate for testing..

Comment: Plus mine works on repl.it :D

Comment: This is pretty spot on. I didn't want to touch the tests as I figured, minor script - but janos brought it up to production levels :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and indeed this is great for production level. You can also check my edit, which is just verifies that @mleyfman is great!

Comment: Also in the second version there is no need to make the first check.. http://repl.it/XHC/10

Answer (score 6):

I came up with a different solution by utilizing Python's magic method for `==` which is `__eq__(self, other`).

I define it in the `User` class like so:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.key == other.key if isinstance(other, User) else False
```

This allows you to do the obvious `User(1) == User(2)` testing but also this allows you to test membership in a collection using the `in` keyword:

```
User(1) in [User(1)] # This will return True
User(1) in [User(2)] # This will return False
```

We can then change the condition slightly to make the `is_ok` function like this:

```
def is_ok(user_dbs, self_db):
    count = len(user_dbs)
    if not self_db:
        return not count
    return count == 1 and self_db in user_dbs or count == 0
```

This has the advantage of being a bit more readable, and hence Pythonic. This might come in handy elsewhere as well.

Another minor point is that if you ever rename `key` to something else or change the structure of your `User` class, this code will still work (remember to update `__eq__`!), while most of the alternatives will break.

Answer (score 2):

The only real optimization I see if taking advantage of Pythons english comprehension to unify the return statement:

So, `is_ok` would read:

```
def is_ok(user_dbs, self_db):
  count = len(user_dbs)
  return not count if not self_db \
      else ((count != 1 or self_db.key == user_dbs[0].key) and count != 2)
```

Here's the repl.it showing it works with the unified return statement: http://repl.it/XHB

Comment: Yes that is one thing, but I was hoping for something better.. :)

Comment: @Lipis I certainly understand that :) janos' answer seems pretty spot on

Answer (score 2):

If you have performance problems I don't think you can gain anything from the snippet you have shown.

Anyway I would write the test:

```
  (count != 1 or self_db.key == user_dbs[0].key) and count != 2
```

as

```
  count != 2 and (count != 1 or self_db.key == user_dbs[0].key)
```

so that in the case `count==2` there is no need to access self_db and user_dbs. This is particularly convinient if the case count==2 is more frequent than count==0.

Comment: No there are no performance issues and maybe the optimize wans't the best word.. I'm looking maybe for a smaller signature or a more readable thingy.. but I'm guessing there is not much we can do.. getting the count in front is a good point though :)

Answer (score 2):

This function can be simplified to:

```
def is_ok(user_dbs, self_db):
    return not user_dbs or (len(user_dbs) == 1 and
                            self_db is not None and
                            user_dbs[0].key == self_db.key)
```

**EDIT**: Forgot to check if `self_db` is None. Fixed, kudos to *Lipis*.

Comment: But this doesn't pass all the required tests

Comment: @janos is right. After running some tests in App Engine I have a small edit in the original question (sorry for that but I didn't think about it in a first place). So the last equality can be changed to: `self_db in user_dbs` and there will be no more errors. Plus since the `AND` operations are being evaluated first the parenthesis is not needed so the whole thing can look like this: `return not user_dbs or len(user_dbs) == 1 and self_db in user_dbs` [repl.it/XHC/7](http://repl.it/XHC/7)

Comment: and I also think that the comment about sanity is not really needed..

Comment: @Will Here you are.. http://repl.it/XHC/9 But the comment about sanity doesn't stand either your code succeeds or fails..

Comment: Lead me or not.. your code is broken and your attitude is not OK..

Comment: I don't need to explain anything actually and what do you need to understand? Your answer is not offering anything better than what is already posted..

Comment: @Lipis It eliminates an unnecessary conditional branch, it eliminates an unnecessary variable (`count`), and it's the most succint and straightforward of all the solutions posted; so how do you figure that it doesn't offer any advantages over the others?

Answer (score 0):

You write the nice breakdown, clear and transparent. What makes you think your program should not be like that?

```
def is_available(this_user, db_users):

    # If there are 0 records then we know for sure that this username is available.
    if not db_users:
        return True

    # If there are 2 records then we know for sure that the particular username is not available.
    if len(db_users) > 1:
        return False

    # If it's a new user then the username is not available
    if not this_user:
        return False

    # If it's an existing user and that user is yourself then the username is available, otherwise not.
    return this_user.key == db_users[0].key
```

Now compare this to some concise, smart and magic solution and imagine yourself reading this code six months later. What would be more understandable?